# Error de sintaxis: SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment, línea: 13, archivo: Código.gs

Tags: javascript

```
     function ProtegerFilaBasadoEnValor() {
       // variables activas
       var celdaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
       var FilaActiva = celdaActiva.getRow()
      var hojaactiva = celdaActiva.getSheet();
       // valores deseados
       var coldeseada= 9;
       var filanodeseada =1
       var nombrehojadeseada = "CONTROL FECHAS";
       var valordeseado= "Proteger";
       if(celdaActiva.getColumn()==coldeseada && celdaActiva.getRow()!= filanodeseada && celdaActiva.getSheet().getName()== nombrehojadeseada
 && celdaActiva.getValue()= valordeseado){
         var proteccion = hojaactiva.getRange(FilaActiva,1,1, hojaactiva.getLastColumn()).protect();
         proteccion.removeEditors([`lopezgrisales1994@gmail.com`])
       }
       function protecciones()}
       ProtegerFilaBasadoEnValor();
     }
```

Comment: Esto no parece java... nunca había visto declarar una función `function NOMBRE` en java, más bien será... JavaScript? Además, aquí no trabajamos para ti, llegar y ponernos tu código sin más no es muy educado...

Comment: @Benito-B me disculpo soy nuevo en el foro, tampoco soy programador estaba haciendo una macro de google sheets, nuevamente ofrezco disculpas porque no entiendo muy bien el protocolo para generar preguntas, a duras penas pude montar mi código . lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima igualmente muchas gracias

Comment: El problema que veo es que en la última comparación de tu `if`, has puesto un único paréntesis (lo cual es una asignación, no una comparación), y eso provocaría el error que indicas... por desgracia, has indicado en qué número de línea está el error, pero no qué línea es esa, así que solo puedo *intuir* que ese es el problema... pero no estar seguro. Me refiero a esto: `&& celdaActiva.getValue()= valordeseado`, ahí falta un `=` en la comparación

Comment: efectivamente me faltaba el signo igual además de un corchete para cerrar el bloque de código. muchas gracias @Benito-B